# Amazon Rekognition for Video - getFaceSearch: index number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I’m new using **Amazon Rekognition** to analyze faces on a video.

I’m using *startFaceSearch* to start my analysis. After the job is completed successfully, I’m using the JobId generated to call *getFaceSearch*.

On my first video analyzed, the results were as expected. But when I analyze the second example some strange behavior occurs and I can’t understand why.

Viewing the JSON generated as results for my second video, completely different faces are identified with the same *index number*.

Please see the results below.

```
{
    "Timestamp": 35960,
    "Person": {
        "Index": 11,
        "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.09375,
            "Height": 0.24583333730698,
            "Left": 0.1875,
            "Top": 0.375
        },
        "Face": {
            "BoundingBox": {
                "Width": 0.06993006914854,
                "Height": 0.10256410390139,
                "Left": 0.24475525319576,
                "Top": 0.375
            },
            "Landmarks": [
                {
                    "Type": "eyeLeft",
                    "X": 0.26899611949921,
                    "Y": 0.40649232268333
                },
                {
                    "Type": "eyeRight",
                    "X": 0.28330621123314,
                    "Y": 0.41610333323479
                },
                {
                    "Type": "nose",
                    "X": 0.27063181996346,
                    "Y": 0.43293061852455
                },
                {
                    "Type": "mouthLeft",
                    "X": 0.25983560085297,
                    "Y": 0.44362303614616
                },
                {
                    "Type": "mouthRight",
                    "X": 0.27296212315559,
                    "Y": 0.44758656620979
                }
            ],
            "Pose": {
                "Roll": 22.106262207031,
                "Yaw": 6.3516845703125,
                "Pitch": -6.2676968574524
            },
            "Quality": {
                "Brightness": 41.875026702881,
                "Sharpness": 65.948883056641
            },
            "Confidence": 90.114051818848
        }
    }
}

{
    "Timestamp": 46520,
    "Person": {
        "Index": 11,
        "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.19034090638161,
            "Height": 0.42083331942558,
            "Left": 0.30681818723679,
            "Top": 0.17916665971279
        },
        "Face": {
            "BoundingBox": {
                "Width": 0.076486013829708,
                "Height": 0.11217948794365,
                "Left": 0.38680067658424,
                "Top": 0.26923078298569
            },
            "Landmarks": [
                {
                    "Type": "eyeLeft",
                    "X": 0.40642243623734,
                    "Y": 0.32347011566162
                },
                {
                    "Type": "eyeRight",
                    "X": 0.43237379193306,
                    "Y": 0.32369664311409
                },
                {
                    "Type": "nose",
                    "X": 0.42121160030365,
                    "Y": 0.34618207812309
                },
                {
                    "Type": "mouthLeft",
                    "X": 0.41044121980667,
                    "Y": 0.36520344018936
                },
                {
                    "Type": "mouthRight",
                    "X": 0.43202903866768,
                    "Y": 0.36483728885651
                }
            ],
            "Pose": {
                "Roll": 0.3165397644043,
                "Yaw": 2.038902759552,
                "Pitch": -1.9931464195251
            },
            "Quality": {
                "Brightness": 54.697460174561,
                "Sharpness": 53.806159973145
            },
            "Confidence": 95.216400146484
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, in this video, all faces have the same index number, regardless of they are different. Any suggestions?

Comment: The [GetFaceSearch documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_GetFaceSearch.html) says "The search returns faces in a collection that match the faces of persons detected in a video." Are you supplying a Face Collection as input? Are the people you want Indexed included in the Face Collection? I suspect that if they aren't found in the collection, they won't receive a unique Index number.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comments. In fact, I don't supply a face collection as input. With this example I only want to extract the faces on that video. In a second step, I'll pretend create a collection using the faces returned.

Comment: Well, it gave you the faces. It just seems that it won't give you a consistent Index unless the faces are in the Face Collection. (That's my assumption from reading the documentation.) When you _do_ add them to a Face Collection, take advantage of the External ID to have a friendly name for the face. See also: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)

Comment: I tested my video on AWS Rekognition Video Demo, uploading it, and the results was as expected. Then I used the same video on my code, using startFaceSearch and getFaceSearch method and the results are different. Not only the index number for persons are different. In a Video Demo, found a person in timestamp 35920 with confidence=98.25. On my test, found a person in timestamp 35960 with confidence=90.11. Any idea?

Comment: No, I wouldn't know why results differ. Only thing might be sorting by Index vs Timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

PersonDetail object is the result of the API . "index" is the identifier for the person detected in the video. So the index doesn't span across videos. It is just an internal reference.

Link below which details Index 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_PersonDetail.html

Comment: Hi @mukund. Do you have any example of how to call PersonDetail on ASW SDK?